# Как остановить анимируемый элемент?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, анимация

Подскажите, как остановить анимируемый элемент (смещение картинки из точки А в точку Б) по достижению нужного места, чтобы он не "прыгал" обратно в положение 0%, а остался на 100%.

```
<style>
            .top-device {
                background-image: url("img");
                width: 169px;
                height: 35px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                animation: top 2s 1;                
            }

                    @keyframes top { 

                    0% {
                        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
                        animation-timing-function: linear;                        
                    }

                    100% {
                        transform: translate3d(30px, 30px, 0px);
                        animation-timing-function: linear;

                    }



                }
</style>
```

**Обновление**

Загвоздка в том, что я анимирую не один элемент, а несколько, последовательно, один за другим (есть большой шкаф, и из него выплывают встроенные блоки в разные стороны). То есть у меня много классов сейчас уже создано, и на них всех висит анимация.

```
$('#foo').appear(function() {
  $(this).text('Hello world');
});
```

В этом коде есть айди и класс, может, можно к моим всем классам применить один айди (#foo), и тогда запуститься плагин, не?

**Обновление**

Это один блок:

```
.top-device {
    outline: 0px solid red;
    background-image: url("../img/top-device.png");
    width: 169px;
    height: 35px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left: 268px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    -webkit-animation: top 1.5s 1;
    animation: top 1.5s 1;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
    animation-delay: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes top { 
    0% 
   {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% 
    {
        transform: translate3d(-265px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Таких блоков 4.Надо все названия анимируемых классов указать в JS скрипте?

У меня есть класс, в котором находятся все классы с анимацией, большой блок див, может, как-то с ним можно сделать appear, чтобы когда этот блок станет виден и начнется анимация? Но в самом этом классе анимации нет, только в классах внутри него!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тадам:

```
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
          animation-fill-mode: both;
```

Это к .top-device добавить.

Ну и [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp)

**Обновление**

Создайте класс animated и анимацию CSS на этот класс повесте. Заюзайте, например, вот этот [плагин](https://github.com/bas2k/jquery.appear/). Когда элемент появляется, просто добавляйте к нужному элементу класс с анимацией и все)

**Обновление 2**

Анимацию на элемент не вешать. Повесить ее на другой класс. Тот плагин помогает словить момент, когда пользователь прокрутил до него и он виден ему. Тогда срабатывает колбэк (там один единственный пример есть), где вам и нужно написать, чтобы к этому элементу добавлялся класс с анимацией.

**Обновление 3**

Вот я делал скорее всего то, что вам нужно: http://demo.meethemes.com/creatorica/theme/   Посмотрите файл http://demo.meethemes.com/creatorica/theme/js/custom.js Там, где `appear: { ...`. Вот там сделано, чтобы с разными анимациями по очереди появлялось красивенько.

Comment: Спасибо это помогло!
А может подскажите еще один момент...
Надо чтобы анимация начиналась не с момента захода на страницу, а когда пользователь прокрутит страницу до нужного места???

Comment: Что то не очень понял...
Создать дополнительный класс помимо уже имеющихся (поверх или под) в нужном месте? И когда этот класс появиться в "поле зрения" начнется анимация, так?
С плагином тоже что то не понял )=

Comment: Вот я делал скорее всего то, что вам нужно: http://demo.meethemes.com/creatorica/theme/ Посмотрите файл http://demo.meethemes.com/creatorica/theme/js/custom.js Там где appear: { ... Вот там сделано, чтобы с разными анимациями по очереди появлялось красивенько

Comment: Красиво сделано, но не то)
Я прикреплю скриншот, чтобы понятнее стало, что мне нужно (=

http://joxi.ru/1A5yKaQinYQ6AE

Надо, чтобы, дойдя до этой части страницы, блоки начали выплывать из этого шкафа. Все в .PNG.

Comment: Ну вот. Анимация есть? Если да, то вешаете appear.js на этот блок, а внутри с setTimeout поочереди на каждый блок .addClass('...')

Comment: Правильно ли я понял? В хтмл код мне нужно вставить следующее:

 appear: function() {
  $('#features').find('.row').appear(function() {
   var $feature = $(this).find('.feature-item');

   if(ie!== false && ie <= 9) $feature.css('opacity', 1);

   $feature.each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
     $this.addClass('animated fadeIn');
    }, i*200);
   });
  });

Предварительно подключив библиотеку appear.js  
И addClass я заменяю на свой класс? А если классов много, то через зпт их ставить или как?

Comment: Ну, вам не через .each можно сделать, а просто несколько setTimeout-ов и в каждом на нужный элемент addClass.